# Manipular o DOM e remover parágrafo vazio antes e depois de um elemento figure?

Tags: javascript, dom

Usando algum método em Javascript, como poderia remover elementos que estão sujando a HTML?

Tenho a seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="container-text">
<p> Teste onon onon noonnoon </p>
<p> Teste onon onon noonnoon </p>
<p> </p>
<figure><img src="/path/img/teste.jpg"></figure>
<p> </p>
<p> Teste onon onon noonnoon </p>
</div>
```

Como poderia remover o parágrafo vazio que está antes de depois de `<figure>` (siblings / irmãos)?

Tentei assim:

```
function removeParagraphAfterAndBeforeFigure(result) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = result;
        el.querySelectorAll('figure')
           .forEach(function(figure){
            figure.parentNode.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(p){
                 if(p.textContent == '' || p.textContent == ' ') {
                     p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
                 }
            });
        })
        result = el.innerHTML;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Se a sua tag estiver assim `<p></p>`, **sem o espaço dentro**, tipo uma tag colada direto na outra, vc pode usar a pseudo classe `:empty` do CSS para dar um display none nesse parágrafo

Comment: Tem que ser irmão diretos do figure? Se tiver um `p` vazio no inicio, ele deve ficar? Ou tem que limpar qualquer paragrafo vazio dentro da `div`, indenpendente de onde ele esteja?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deu certo assim:

```
    function removeParagraphAfterAndBeforeFigure(result) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = result;
        el.querySelectorAll('figure').forEach(function(value) {
            if(value.nextElementSibling.nodeName == 'P' && (value.nextElementSibling.textContent == '' || value.nextElementSibling.textContent == ' ')) {
                value.parentNode.removeChild(value.nextElementSibling)
            }
            if(value.previousElementSibling.nodeName == 'P' && (value.previousElementSibling.textContent == '' || value.previousElementSibling.textContent == ' ')) {
                value.parentNode.removeChild(value.previousElementSibling)
            }
        })
        result = el.innerHTML;
        return result; 
    }
```